# Inserting or Reading from Hive with HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand how spark works with HDFS/Hive..

If i am using HiveContext to read or write to hive, will it generate a map reduce job on the hadoop cluster end?

Which resources(spark or Hadoop) will be used to perform the statements on hc.sql(****);

```
SQLContext hc = new HiveContext(jssc.sparkContext());
Dataset<Row> df = hc.createDataFrame(schemaRDD, mySchema.class);
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myView");
hc.sql("SELECT * from HIVE_TABLE"); 
hc.sql("INSERT INTO ......"from myView");
```

Comment: Voted to close. Look for HiveContext in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: Spark does not generate a map reduce job. It is just Spark.